# laravel jetstream component how to pass active class as parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel Jestream. I am also adding "dark theme" support for my application. I am using Laravel 8 Jetstream with Tailwind 3.

So far, I have successfully set dark classes for the navigation links in the `resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php` file like so:

```xml
<!-- Navigation Links -->
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
    <x-jet-nav-link class="dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-blue-300" href="{{ route($ruta_dashboard) }}" :active="request()->routeIs($ruta_dashboard)">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </x-jet-nav-link>
</div>
```

So far so good.

However, when I try to add the dark class to the `dark:active:bg-amber-200` class like this

```xml
<!-- Navigation Links -->
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
    <x-jet-nav-link class="dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-blue-300 dark:active:bg-amber-200" href="{{ route($ruta_dashboard) }}" :active="request()->routeIs($ruta_dashboard)">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </x-jet-nav-link>
</div>
```

It doesn't work.

how do I pass the active classes for dark mode to the Laravel Jetstream components?

Comment: what version of Tailwind are you using? I think in Tailwind 1 and 2, stacking dark and active doesn't work seamlessly

Comment: @IGP Tailwind 3

Answer (score 0):

Good morning dear, I had the same problem and I managed to find the solution. It turns out that the dark class must be specified inside the Jetstream component located in the folder:

vendor/laravel/jetstream/resources/views/components

Modified component example:

```
@props(['active'])

@php
$classes = ($active ?? false)
            ? 'block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 border-indigo-400 text-base font-medium text-indigo-700 bg-indigo-50 focus:outline-none focus:text-indigo-800 focus:bg-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-700 transition dark:bg-slate-700 dark:border-slate-500'
            : 'block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 border-transparent text-base font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-800 focus:bg-gray-50 focus:border-gray-300 transition dark:hover:border-slate-500';

<a {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => $classes]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

I got this information in this video (min 11:35).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU3IrFmOGNQ

It should be clarified that it is in Spanish but it is understood

Tell us if you were able to solve the problem

Cheers